# PHP - Two Widgetized Div's in One (non widget) Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble trying to get two widgetized div's nestled inside one div. I have the CSS down, it's just the PHP coding part in the main page. The functions are working perfectly, and I already have the widgets running perfect where they need to be in the widget area.

I want it to display as;

```
Home Display
>Home Display Left (then close div)
>Home Display Right (then close div)
(close Home Display div)
```

This is my code:

```
function home_display_left() {
    echo '<div class="home-display"><div class="display-left"><div class="wrap">';
    genesis_widget_area( 'home-display-left', array(
        'before' => '<div class="home-display-left">',
        <div class="display-right"><div class="wrap">';
        genesis_widget_area( 'home-display-right', array(
            'before' => '<div class="home-display-right">',
            'after' => '</div>',
        ) 
    );
    echo '</div></div></div></div>';
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or help me by providing me the right code based off of above?

Thanks!

Comment: Watch out... there are some typos. You probably will see the response by yourself if you give you're code a proper formatting.

Comment: There a quite a bit of typos in there, as @Alrik mentioned. Hint: everything that is opened must be closed.

Comment: Ohhhh... that was skipped from my mind. Thanks for making me remind. Its working well now :) thank You. Sometimes while coding we skip miner things.